# Why MongoDB not running SSL?

Tags: ssl, mongodb-3.4

I need to run MongoDB with SSL, the version that is currently installed is ***3.4.16*** without SSL.

Can I download 3.4.16 with SSL and just stop the service copy the Bin files across and then start up the service again, in it's simplistic form?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and short. Yes, that's the right way to do it.